# Android emulator not showing in the flutter target selector?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I've been trying to set up flutter for a while and with various attempts (even after rebooting my machine and starting again), I keep getting this same problem. Despite having set up and emulator, neither the target selector, nor flutter doctor recognise the emulator and it won't run either

I wonder if the problem is to do with the hardware acceleration. I am trying to achieve this on a few year old i3 Lenovo IdeaPad 310-15ISK 80SM. I've followed all the steps of set-up precisely so cannot think of a problem. The only times I haven't been sure are on the first step (enable VM acceleration on my machine), and the 5th (Under Emulated Performance, select Hardware - GLES 2.0 to enable hardware acceleration). This is when I set it up, the only option was 'automatic' and the software wouldn't let me alter that.

[Emulator not running, or showing in target selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm2hl.gif)

As you can see, despite an emulator existing it is neither running nor showing in the target selector. I am running the latest versions of flutter and android studio. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Try to wipe the emulator data? What does android studio logs say?

Comment: use 'adb devices -l' to see if adb detect, can be another error

Comment: @SwiftingDuster Great suggestion. It's told me that hardware acceleration needs to be enabled. From the flutter site it seems that Intel HAXM needs to be downloaded. After following the steps on the site no download is happening...i'm continuing to look into this

Comment: Download it from android studio's sdk manager

Comment: @SwiftingDuster it appears that intel HAXM is already installed and im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I meet this question. sorry for my English level.

command:

```
  flutter doctor
```

basic information:
because of not find Android SDK path.

how to solution:
Add android sdk path of custom

**First step:**

```
 ## here is android root SDK -- custom path
 export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/custom_path/android_sdk_home";
 export PATH=$PATH:$ANRDOID_SDK_ROOT
```

**Second step:**
source `.bash_profile`

Third step:
restart IDE

It has worked for me. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).